# Groovy help find missing package: com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials package not found, Jenkins Job DSL plugin

Tags: tomcat, groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm new to groovy and currently am trying to update my teams Jenkins server from 1.6 to 2.7. One of the pieces I need to migrate is the Job DSL which we have in version control.

On the new server when I try and run the old job DSL I get the below error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/apps/Jenkins/workspace/DSL-infrastructure/shared/Shared.groovy: 10: Apparent variable 'com' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a class name or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'com' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 10, column 17.
       def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
                   ^
```

Basically, I think the issue is that the groovy script cannot find the com.cloudbees... package.

The Shared.groovy script section:

```
  static def getCred(partialName) {
    def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
      com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
      jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance,
      null,
      null
    )
    creds.find { it.description.contains(partialName) }
  }
```

I have searched high and low and cannot for the life of me figure out why or how to resolve this missing package issue. It gets complicated as I'm running Jenkins inside apache tomcat.

I am not sure how to import this missing package inside an apache tomcat server running Jenkins? I found the .jar file inside directory:

```
/apps/jenkins/plugins/credentials/WEB-INF/lib/credentials.jar
```

The specific class I'm trying to reference:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/CredentialsProvider.java

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.43 of the Job DSL plugin, classes from the Credentials plugins are no longer available in DSL scripts. So you probably also updated the Job DSL plugin when updating Jenkins.

Version 1.21+ of the [Credentials plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) allows to specify custom IDs for credentials, so it should not be necessary to find credentials by description. Just use a descriptive ID instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply daspilker. I had a gut feeling I would need to rewrite the Job DSL. I will give it a go and post my answer here if I come up with one.

Comment: Could you show an example of how it would work just with the Credentials plugin?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use the [Credential Binding](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs) plugin that allows to use already defined Jenkins global [credentials](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) as suggested by [daspilker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271460/daspilker).
Below is an example of a job that is listing the folder structure from an SVN url (it will work similary for other repos). Note that you need to **concatenate the secret**, using a formater will mask it and it won't be recognized (below the user wasn't concatenated for simplicity).

[image: Jenkins Secrets]